# Передача кастомных элементов в bundle | Android

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

Как мне передать кастомный тип элементы в Bundle. Например, я хочу передать List, но не понимаю как. Почитал статьи и прочее, но после всех попыток получал только ошибки. Сейчас уже не могу сказать, какие точно. Может ли кто-то объяснить мне, как сделать это правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов отправки списка List. Первый способ как и второй  - заполнение списка объектами класса который вам нужен и отправка. При это класс должен быть либо [parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) либо [serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable), но лучше использовать parcelable. Пример serializable класса:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Hospitals(int id, String name)
    {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
    }
  ....
}
```

Дальше вы из этого list делаете arraylist:

```
List<ClassObject> yourList = ...;
ArrayList<ClassObject> arrList = new ArrayList<>(yourList.size());
arrList.addAll(yourList);
```

и отправляете через bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("valuesArray", arrList);
```

Второй вариант - конвертируем ваш объект в json и отправляем в через bundle как стринг:

```
String jsonList = gson.toJson(yourList);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(...);
```

Но стоить помнить что у bundle есть ограничение на 1MB ([пруф](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles#sdbp)):

> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1MB,
> which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process.

Поэтому третий вариант будет без использования bundle вообще. Нужно создать класс в котором будет поле вашего списка и после заполнения этого списка в активности вы должны сетить этот список в отдельный класс. После того как список теперь находится и в другом классе тоже, то значит вы можете его взять откуда угодно в том числе и с целевой активности. Для начала создаем класс-синглтон:

```
public class Single {

    private static final Single INSTANCE = new Single();

    private Single(){}


    public static Single getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

дальше создаем в нем поле вашего массива и метод чтобы взять этот массив и добавить в него данные:

```
List<YourObject> myList = new List()
public List<YourObject> getArray() {
     return this.myList ;
}
public void addToArray(YourObject obj) {
     myList.add(obj);
}
```

и теперь вы можете засетить данные:

```
Sindle.getInstance().getArray()
```

и взять данные:

```
Sindle.getInstance().myList
```

[Вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152454/arraylist-initialized-accessed-using-singleton-class) работы с синглтоном. Если же вам нужно добавить сразу весь список а не по одному элементу то нужно использовать `addAll()`. Вот [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List) про List. Ну и последний вариант - использовать [sharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Этот метод не совсем хорош для таких целей но задачу тоже можно выполнить:

```
Set<String> tasksSet = new HashSet<String>(objList);
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    .edit()
    .putStringSet("tasks_set", tasksSet)
    .commit();
```

и считываем его где вам нужно:

```
Set<String> tasksSet = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    .getStringSet("tasks_set", new HashSet<String>());
List<String> tasksList = new ArrayList<String>(tasksSet);
```

Так же в sharedPreferences можно записать стринг json (конвертировать так как я выше показывал) и взять где вам нужно. Запись:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("some_key", value).apply();
```

и считываем где вам нужно:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String data = settings.getString("some_key", "defaultValue");
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный ответ. Думаю, я попробую все варианты и выберу для себя лучший.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew забыл только указать (упомянул вскольз) про штатный вариант с `Parcelable`.

Между тем, это штатный (нативный для Android) вариант, который в силу своей реализации обеспечивает очень быструю передачу и без использования сериализации и связанных с этим ограничений, в частности в документации пишется, что:

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport.

То есть по сути `Parcelable` - это специальный протокол передачи данных между разными процессами, который опирается на низкоуровневую реализацию с использованием особенностей реализации ядра ОС Android.

Для использования этого протокола нужно своем классе реализовать интерфейс `Parcelable` со статическим полем `CREATOR`, далее уже как обычно: `putParcelable()/getParcelable()`

Для сравнения эффективность `Parcelable` vs. `Serializable`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]